# Why in nested loop after 4%4==0 programm does not print 4?

Tags: c

The program displays prime numbers from 1 to 10, and works fine. But why when i becomes 4 and j becomes 4 - it  doesn't go inside if condition of 4%4==0, and 4 is not displayed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k = 1;

 for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
      k=0;
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            k++;
        }
        if(k==1)
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I do not sleep well at night thinking about this issue.` LOL, Don't think hard :D

Comment: A number is always divisible by itself and 1, and your loop starts from 2, not 1. But it ends with the number itself, so I suggest changing the loop to `for(j=2; j<i; j++)`

Comment: `4%2` is also 0 - `k` will equal 2 at the end of the inner loop.

Comment: `4 % 2 == 0` too, so `k = 2` and the printf never executes.

Comment: `from 1 to 100`...you sure? All I see is `for(i=2;i<=10;i++)`...

Comment: "Doesn't goes" is unclear; which question would you like to ask? You can [edit] your post to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `i = 4` the `j` loop starts at `j = 2` and `4%2 == 0`, so `k` is set to 1. When after 2 loops `j` is 4, `4%4 == 0` again and `k` is incremented to 2. At the exit of the loop `k` is 2 therefore `k==1` is false thus `printf` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

When I edited your code to show the value of k for every i, I got 2 for i=4 which means once for 2 and second time for 4. So it means 4%4==0 and 4%2==0 evaluated to be true.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k = 1;

 for(i=2;i<=100;i++)
    {
      k=0;
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            k++;
        }

        printf("%d -- %d\n",i,k);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Output showing value of k for every i ::

[image]